# Dynamic label position stat_poly_eq and ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using ggplot, I am displaying a range of points, a third order polynomial fit(with corresponding formula and R2 value) and a standardised function for comparison.

```
ggplot(aes(x = saturation, y = time_norm_ratio), data = tmp) + geom_point(aes(color = id)) +
  geom_line(aes(x=saturation,y=BPR_time_norm_ratio,color="BPR function")) + geom_smooth(aes(color = id), method= "lm", se = F, formula=y ~ poly(x, 3, raw=TRUE)) +
  ggtitle("Saturation time delay curve") +
  labs(x="Saturation",y="Time (t/to)") +
  stat_poly_eq(aes(label=paste(..eq.label..,..adj.rr.label.., sep = "~~~")),geom="label",alpha=0.33,formula=(y ~ poly(x, 3, raw=TRUE)),label.y=2.5,parse=TRUE) +
  theme(text=element_text(size=20))
```

Giving me:

[image: Output]

However, as I am plotting for a range of files I wish to standardise the location of the `stat_poly_eq` box on the plot. It is currently fixed at y=2.5 `(label.y=2.5)`. Is it possible to set it's y location dynamically relative to the y axis?

I tried the following:

```
label.y=(0.75(tmp.time_norm_ratio)
```

But this resulted in:

> Error in ggplot2::layer(stat = StatPolyEq, data = data, mapping = mapping,  :
> attempt to apply non-function

Comment: Think the problem is likely with ```0.75(tmp.time_norm_ratio)```, should this be ```0.75 * tmp$time_norm_ratio``` instead? Probably need some aggregation as well, like ```label.y = 0.75 * max(tmp$time_norm_ratio)```.

Comment: Correct! Feel free to post as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***(Comment converted to answer)***

Think the problem is likely with

```
0.75(tmp.time_norm_ratio)
```

should this be

```
0.75 * tmp$time_norm_ratio
```

instead? Probably need some aggregation as well, like

```
label.y = 0.75 * max(tmp$time_norm_ratio)
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is just set the label.y = (between 0 to 1)